# Mean and variance of number of tries required

Tags: distributions, variance, mean

So the question states that I'm trying something with an 85% chance of success, if I don't succeed  I try again until I do. What is the mean and variance of the number of tries necessary until I succeed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the trials are independent, you're looking for the [waiting time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Waiting_time_in_a_Bernoulli_process) $T$ of a [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) process with probability $p=0.85$ and failure $q=1-p$, which is a [Geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). You can easily compute the mean and variance by these formulae,
$$\mathbb{E}(T) = \frac{1}{p}~,$$
$$\mathbb{V}(T) = \frac{q}{p^2}~.$$